# JPQL how to fetch all referenced entities and not just searched by

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jpql

Let's say I have 2 entities - Item and Tag. Every Item has a list of Tags. I want to supply a list of tag ids and return all items that contain those tags.
Currently query is like `select item from Item item join fetch item.tags tags where tags.id in tagIds`.
Only supplied tags are getting fetched(E.g. if I supply just one tag id, item.tags contains that one tag), but I'd like to fetch all of them.
I'm using spring data, so jpa provider is hibernate, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that JPA filters child entities if they are in "where" clause. One way around it is making a subquery:

```
select item from Item item left join fetch item.tags tags where exists(select t from tags where t.id in :tagsIds)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use left join to fetch all.

change your query as follow.

```
@Query("select item from Item item left join fetch item.tags tags where tags.id in :tagIds")
List<Item> findItemsByTagIds(@Param("tagIds") List<Long> listOfTagIds);
```

If you want distinct item then you can use distinct keyword after select.

Comment: Left join for some reason does not work with a where.

Answer (score 0):

And if you have the reverse relation from tag to item you can request :

select distinct t.item from Tag t where t.id in tagIds